# how to post input value from jquery datatables in asp.net core 3

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, datatables

my datatable have 4 input column that user can edit that values...

i want to post that values to my ASP.net [POST] action

my code doesn't work correctly

**my datatable**

```
var table = $("#tblEmployees").DataTable(
                        {
                            language: {
                                url: '/lib/datatables/plugins/fa.json'
                            },
                            ajax: {
                                url: "/Salary/LoadData",
                                type: "POST",
                                datatype: "json"
                            },
                            columns: [
                                { "data": "EmployeeId" },
                                { "data": "EmpId" },
                                { "data": "EmpFamily" },
                                { "data": "ShiftWork" },
                                {
                                    "render": function(data, type, row) { return '<input type="text" class="form-control datatable_input DataTable_WorkDay" Id="DataTable_WorkDay_Input_' + row.EmployeeId + '" value=" ' + row.WorkDay + '" />'; }
                                },
                                {
                                    "render": function(data, type, row) { return '<input type="text" class="form-control datatable_input DataTable_OverTimeHour" Id="DataTable_OverTimeHour_Input_' + row.EmployeeId + '" value=" ' + row.OverTimeHour + '" />'; }
                                },
                                {
                                    "render": function(data, type, row) { return '<input type="text" class="form-control datatable_input DataTable_HolidayDay" Id="DataTable_HolidayDay_Input_' + row.EmployeeId + '" value=" ' + row.HolidayDay + '" />'; }
                                },
                                {
                                    "render": function(data, type, row) { return '<input type="text" class="form-control datatable_input DataTable_MissionDay" Id="DataTable_MissionDay_Input_' + row.EmployeeId + '" value=" ' + row.MissionDay + '" />'; }
                                }
                            ],
                            dom: 'Blfrtip',
                            buttons: ['excel'],
                            select: true,
                            paging: true,
                            lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                            fixedHeader: true
                        });
```

I change the valeu of inputs and then click on submit button

**my click function:**

```
 $('#btnSalarySubmit').click(function () {
            var table = $('#tblEmployees').DataTable();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Salary/GetData",
                data: JSON.stringify(table.rows().data().toArray()),,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json"
            });
        });
```

**my /Salary/GetData function**

```
public void GetData([FromBody] List<worktime> model)
    {
        var x = model;
    }
```

values in input Does not exist in my model variable and it returns 0 (my first value)

Answer (score 1):

From `table.rows().data().toArray()`, the result is a multivariate array. The format of JSON passed into the backend is incorrect.

Because I don't know your json, so I give an example.

In the view, this is a table.

```
<table id="tblEmployees" class="table table-condensed">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>EmployeeId</th>
        <th>EmpFamily</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>bcd</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<button id="btnSalarySubmit">Submit</button>
```

**Javascript**, format the data to an object array.

```
$('#btnSalarySubmit').click(function () {
        var table = $('#tblEmployees').DataTable();
        var jsonData=[]
    
        //It’s important here to convert the data into an array of objects
        $(table.data()).each(function (index, obj) {
            jsonData.push({
                "EmployeeId": parseInt(obj[0]),
                "EmpFamily": obj[1]
            })
        })
        

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Salary/GetData",
            data: JSON.stringify(jsonData),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data)
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log('--error--')
            }
        });
    });
```

The bakend

```
    public IActionResult GetData([FromBody] List<worktime> model)
    {
        return Ok(model);
    }
```

Model

```
public class worktime
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string EmpFamily { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @masoud, could you accept this answer, or do you have any other issues?